# What should I do with the answers given when they did not solve the problem?

Tags: discussion, support

I don't know what to do with the answers when the answers given by all didn't solve the problem. Why should I accept the answers when they don't solve the issue?

Please refer to this question:

[How to create Regular expression to Omit Unicode character 'θ'?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24930709/3493471)

The users answered, but it didn't solve there. What should I do?

One more issue: When I want to ask a new question the following message is displayed:

> **Wait! Some of your past questions have not been well-received, and you're in danger of being blocked from asking any more.
>   For help formulating a clear, useful question, see: How do I ask a good question?
>   Also, edit your previous questions to improve formatting and clarity.**

Now, what should I do?
q

Comment: Also, in regards to one of your comments on the second answer: Your question is not a "ticket" and will likely not be closed if it's a good question, so that it may help educate future users. That said, I'm not sure if this will really help future users...

Comment: and you can probably edit your question with some sample input/output so that it's easier for everyone else to verify answers.  you might want to include a link to http://rubular.com/, a light-weight regex testing tool

Comment: Your new edit is an entirely different issue. Try searching about it here on Meta, it's been asked before.

Comment: [This](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255583/) is what your new edit is leading to. You should read that page carefully, to see what you're preventing.

Comment: **Wait! Some of your past questions** ... were all the same, actually. Don't do that.

Answer (score 3):

You don't have to do anything, in fact, if the answer didn't solve your problem, then it's probably better if you don't accept the answer.

The whole reason we let the OP control the acceptance of answers is because the OP has a real problem, and we're interested in what the solution to that real problem was.  If an answer doesn't solve that problem, then don't accept.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But when i want to ask new question, the message is displayed for which i am editing the question.

Answer (score 0):

The most constructive thing to do with answers that look somewhat plausible but do not solve your problem is to edit the question to add them to the discussion of what you considered and/or tried and what happened.

For your question, I would set up a freestanding test program with some strings and code to report any errors in the matching. Put the source code for your test program in the question. You could then plug in your own attempts and each answer suggestion, and include the program output for each regex in the question.

That sort of editing would have several benefits. It would improve the quality of the question, possibly attracting upvotes that might reduce your risk of a question ban. It would be a legitimate edit that would naturally bring it back to being in the active question lists without provoking any negative reaction. Given a test program people might be inspired to try out more ideas, which could result in an answer that really does solve your problem.